# gulp-ruby-sass errors out with undefined is not a function

Tags: gulp, gulp-ruby-sass

I am trying to run the `sass` task in my config with `gulp-ruby-sass`,this is the error that I get(the error will be followed by my config and code):

```
 [04:57:11] TypeError: undefined is not a function
at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe [as _pipe] (E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\no
de_modules\gulp-autoprefixer\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\
lib\_stream_readable.js:516:8)
    at DestroyableTransform.pipe2 (E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\node_modules\gulp-plu
mber\index.js:70:20)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\gulp\tasks\sass.js:15:8)
    at module.exports (E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\or
chestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\node_modules\gulp\nod
e_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\node_modules\gulp\nod
e_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
    at E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrator\index
.js:279:18
    at finish (E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\orchestrat
or\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
    at module.exports (E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\or
chestrator\lib\runTask.js:60:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\node_modules\gulp\nod
e_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
[04:57:11] gulp-ruby-sass stderr: OptionParser::InvalidOption: invalid option: -
-sourcemap-path=app/css
  Use --trace for backtrace.
E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\node_modules\gulp-autoprefixer\node_modules\through2\nod
e_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:523
    dest.end();
         ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\node_modules\gulp-aut
oprefixer\node_modules\through2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readabl
e.js:523:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.g (events.js:199:16)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:129:20)
    at E:\Do\angular-jspm-todo\node_modules\gulp-autoprefixer\node_modules\throu
gh2\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:965:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

My config for the sass task looks like this:

```
    sass: {
        src:  app + '/scss/**/*.{sass,scss}',
        dest: app + '/css',
  options: {
    noCache: true,
    compass: false,
    sourcemap: true,
    sourcemapPath: app+'/css'
  }
},
autoprefixer: {
  browsers: [
    'last 2 versions',
    'safari 5',
    'ie 8',
    'ie 9',
    'opera 12.1',
    'ios 6',
    'android 4'
  ],
  cascade: true
},
scsslint: {
  src: [
    app + '/scss/**/*.{sass,scss}',
    ]
}
```

The `sass` task is here:

```
gulp.task('sass',function(){
return sass(config.sass.src,config.sass.options)
           .pipe(plumber({errorHandler:notify.onError('<%= error.message %>')}))
           .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
           .pipe(autoprefixer(config.autoprefixer))
           .pipe(filter)
           .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.',{includeContent:false}))
           .pipe(filter.restore())
           .pipe(gulp.dest(config.sass.dest));
});
```

This is my `scsslint` task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var scsslint = require('gulp-scss-lint');
var config   = require('../config').scsslint;

gulp.task('scsslint',function(){
    return gulp.src(config.src)
               .pipe(scsslint(config.options))
});
```

I execute them for `browser-sync` and in the `watch` task:

```
 gulp.task('serve',['jshint','scsslint','sass'],function(){
browserSync(config);
```

});

gulp.task('watch',['serve'],function(){
    gulp.watch(config.jshint,['jshint']);
    gulp.watch(config.sass,['scsslint','sass']);
});

Comment: What is line 15 in your `sass.js`?

Comment: Also what is the value of `app` in `sourcemapPath: app+'/css'`?

Comment: @LimH.  Line 15: `.pipe(filter)` ,filter is actually `gulp-filter` I got this [from here](http://stefanimhoff.de/2014/gulp-tutorial-4-css-generation-sass/)

Comment: @LimH. This is the variable app in my config `var app = 'app'`

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems I can see from the stack trace:

1 - I think you forgot this `var filter = gulpFilter(['*.css', '!*.map']);` before doing `pipe(filter)`

2 - If you read the doc of gulp-ruby-sass here, there is no sourcemapPath option: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass

Comment: Everything almost works but there is this issue `[05:50:46] gulp-ruby-sass stderr: Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen -
 *.css
  Use --trace for backtrace.`

Comment: can you change *.css inside gulpFilter into *.scss?

Comment: I have changed the line to `var filter = gulpFilter(['!*.scss', '!*.map']);` but the error seems to persist.I have also tried without the exclamation as well `*.scss`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a glob for your sources. From the [gulp-ruby-sass README](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass#important):

> gulp-ruby-sass doesn't support globs yet, only single files or directories. Just like Sass.

To fix, change your config to:

`src:  app + '/scss'`